# Creating an order-preserving multi-value dict for Django

Tags: python, django, dependency-injection, multiple-inheritance, super

When attempting to make a cross-compatible order preserving `QueryDict` subclass:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from django.http import QueryDict
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

class OrderedQueryDict(QueryDict, OrderedDict):
    pass

querystring = 'z=33&x=11'
print(QueryDict(querystring).urlencode())
print(OrderedQueryDict(querystring).urlencode())
```

Output on Python 3.x (correct and expected result):

```
z=33&x=11  # or maybe x=11,z=33 on Python<=3.5
z=33&x=11
```

Output on Python 2.7 (this querystring was corrupted):

```
x=11&z=33
z=3&z=3&x=1&x=1
```

**Why does this idea work on Python 3 but not on Python 2?**

Django v1.11.20.

Comment: Interestingly, if you use `urllib.urlencode(OrderedQueryDict(querystring))`, it outputs the correct (expected) result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: Re-implement `lists`:

```
class OrderedQueryDict(QueryDict, OrderedDict):
    def lists(self):
        """Returns a list of (key, list) pairs."""
        return [(key, self.getlist(key)) for key in self]
```

For full functionality, `iterlists` should be re-implemented as well.

---

The problem is that Django's `MultiValueDict` overwrites `__getitem__` to retrieve just the last value, with `getlist` retrieving all values. This implicitly relies on other methods of the underlying mapping not using overridden methods. For example, it relies on `super().iteritems` being able to retrieve lists of values:

```
>>> from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict
>>> d = MultiValueDict({"k": ["v1", "v2"]})
>>> d.items()
[('k', 'v2')]
>>> super(MultiValueDict, d).items()
[('k', ['v1', 'v2'])]
```

The [original code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1c9cb948d7b0c264d244763b6682ab790a6b90a0/django/utils/datastructures.py#L190-L212) uses `six` to cover both Python 2 and 3. This is what Python 2 executes:

```
def lists(self):
    return list(self.iterlists())

def iterlists(self):
    """Yields (key, list) pairs."""
    return super(MultiValueDict, self).iteritems()
```

In Python 2, `OrderedDict` is implemented in pure-Python and relies on `self[key]`, i.e. `__getitem__`, to retrieve values:

```
def iteritems(self):
    'od.iteritems -> an iterator over the (key, value) pairs in od'
    for k in self:
        yield (k, self[k])
```

As such, it picks up the overridden `__getitem__` from the MRO and returns only individual values, not the entire lists.

This problem is sidestepped in most builds of Python 3.5+, since `OrderedDict` usually has a C-implementation available, accidentally shielding its methods from using overridden ones.

> collections.OrderedDict is now implemented in C, which makes it 4 to 100 times faster.[[What's new in Python 3.5]](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html)

Comment: This is good, but to make the answer really complete, you could add a bit about customizing the metaclass mro.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro).

Comment: @wim I do not think that would be helpful here. The mro and super lookups are correct. The issue is that MuliValueDict breaks the symmetry of __getitem__ and items. In other words, MultiValueDict is not a dict, and should have used composition instead.

Comment: `MultiValueDict` does not break the symmetry of `__getitem__` and `items`.  They are consistent.  I would agree that composition would have been a better design choice for Django (this class violates [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), but it is what it is...